# What are the differences between a fiber bundle and a sheaf?

Tags: sheaf-theory, fiber-bundles

They are similar. Both contain a projection map and one can define sections, moreover the fiber of the fiber bundle is just like the stalk of the sheaf.

But what are the differences between them?

Maybe a sheaf is more abstract and can break down, while a fibre bundle is more geometric and must keep itself continuous. Any other differences?

Comment: Fibre bundles look the same locally at any point of your space. This does not have to be true for sheaves.

Comment: I have been told (but do not understand) that there is an adjunction between the category of presheaves on a topological space and the category of bundles over the space, which restricts to an equivalence of categories between the category of sheaves and the category of étale bundles.

Comment: a fiber bundle is a local product, and a sheaf of (say rings) is a way of associating rings to the open sets of a space so that inclusions of open sets induce homomorphisms of the respective rings.  theyre just different things

Comment: @yoyo: There are many kinds of sheaves other than sheaves of rings.  A fibre bundle gives rise to a sheaf of sections, from which (in reasonable circumstances, and when endowed with the appropriate extra structure) the bundle can be recovered.  So, while they are different things, it is not a matter of them being *just* different things.

Comment: Sheaves and fiber bundles are different in general. For example the projection $ \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R} $ on the first factor is a (trivial) fiber bundle, but not a sheaf.
The intersection of sheaves and fiber bundles is locally constant sheaves or equivalently, covering spaces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is a ringed topological space, you can look at locally free sheaves of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules on $X$.

If $\mathcal{O}_X$ is the sheaf of continuous functions on a topological manifold (=Hausdorff and locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$), or the sheaf of smooth functions on a smooth manifold, you get fiber bundles (the sheaf associated to a fiber bundle is the sheaf of "regular" (=continuous or smooth here) sections).

Comment: ... and conversely any fiber bundle has a natural sheaf associated to it, namely the sheaf of sections of the bundle.

Answer (score 3):

First remark, there is the definition of [sheaf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_%28mathematics%29) from wikipedia (which by the way talks about étalé spaces and that adjunction business) and the équivalent one 1.2. p. 3 of Bredon, Glen E. (1997), "Sheaf theory" which looks much more like that of a bundle (the A in that definition is the étalé space).

The second remark (from [this p.2-3](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.0995.pdf)) is that a bundle is locally homeomorphic to a cartesian product, whereas a sheaf is locally homeomorphic to the "base space" itself!

Other difference is that a manifold (which a bundle is) is Hausforff, not the étalé space.

Answer (score 0):

A fiber bundle is a quadruple
$$(\mathcal{M},\pi,\mathcal{E},\mathcal{F})$$
(where $\mathcal{M},\mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ are topological spaces) with
$$\pi:\mathcal{E}\to\mathcal{M}$$
such that for every $x\in\mathcal{M}$, there exists a $U\subset\mathcal{M}$ with $x\in U$ and an homeomorphism
$$\chi:\pi^{-1}(U)\to U\times\mathcal{F}$$
such that:
$$\chi\circ pr_1=\pi$$
(where $pr_1:\mathcal{M}\times\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{M}$ is the projection onto the first component, i.e. $\forall (m,f)\in\mathcal{M}\times\mathcal{F}:pr_1(m,f)=m$)

---

In other words in a fiber bundle what is required is a homeomorphism with a cartesian product (locally). Which means that the total space $\mathcal{E}$ has to be locally homeomorphic to $\mathcal{M}\times\mathcal{F}$.

---

In a sheaf, the only requirement is that a topological space $\mathcal{E}$ is locally homeomorphic to another topological space $\mathcal{X}$, in fact a sheaf is a triple:
$$(\mathcal{E},\pi,\mathcal{X})$$
such that $\pi$ is a surjective local homeomorphism.